# Objective C - setImage results in blurry image

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I'm swapping an image of a button when a user click on it.
This button lives in a UITableViewCell.

```
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_on"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

However, the image shows up blurry. If I start interacting with the table though, the blurriness disappear.

How can I prevent that blurriness from showing up in the first place?

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Please share the code on how you declare the button in UITableViewCell.